# How to set svg width and height?

Tags: html, css, svg

i have a 3 svg icon with different viewBox value.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 16"></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

How i can set my svg width and height with same value, so all of these 3 icon will have the same size.

```
<div>
    <span>
          <svg></svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Same size how? Same width, or same height?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All three icons will scale to the same size if you give them the same `width` and `height`.  The shorter one will centre itself.

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

If, by "same size", you mean same height. Then just set the `height` only, and leave the browser to adjust the width based on the viewBox aspect ratio.

```css
svg {
  height: 50px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It seems that if the viewBox attribute is not present in the svg entity (this happens with some generators) this does not work. A detailed explanation on the topic can be read in: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/